# Laravel Json ForeachLoop

Tags: php, json, laravel

I am trying to display a json file in my view.

My JSOn looks like this:

```
    {
     "title": "Chilli Cheddar",
     "body": "Beefburger mit Cheddar Cheese, scharfem Jalapenos Relish und hausgemachte Burgersauce",
     "price": "7,90 €",
     "vendor": "Schräglage" 
    },
    {
     "title": "Kleiner gemischter Salat",
     "body": "Beefburger mit Cheddar Cheese, scharfem Jalapenos Relish und hausgemachte Burgersauce",
     "price": "3,00 €",
     "vendor": "Schräglage" 
    },
    {
     "title": "Brotloser Burger mit Salat",
     "body": "Burger - Brötchen und Salat",
     "price": "7,90 €",
     "vendor": "Schräglage" 
    },
    {
     "title": "Chicken Burger",
     "body": "Burger mit herzhaftem Hähnchenbrustfilet, Tomaten, Salat, Zwiebeln und hausgemachter Burgersauce",
     "price": "7,90 €",
     "vendor": "Schräglage" 
    }
```

When I loop trough the array with:

```
@foreach($json["dish"] as $key => $item)
            @foreach($item as $key => $one)
              <div class="card card-horizontal">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="image" style="background-image: url({{asset('images/frontend/profile/profileHero.jpg')}}); background-size: cover; background-position: center center;">
                      <img src="{{asset('images/frontend/profile/profileHero.jpg')}}" alt="..." style="display: none;">
                      <div class="filter filter-azure">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-neutral btn-round">
                            <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> SMÄCKT MIR
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-7">
                       <div class="content">


                          <a class="card-link" href="#">
                              <h2 class="title">{{$item["title"]}}</h2>
                          </a>
                          <a class="card-link" href="#">

                                @if(array_has($item, 'body'))
                                <h4>{{$item["body"]}}</h4>
                                @endif


                              <br />
                              <h4 class="text-info">{{$item["price"]}}</h4>
                          </a>
                           <div class="footer">
                              <div class="stats">
                                  <a class="card-link" href="#">
                                     <i class="fa fa-male"></i> {{$item["vendor"]}}
                                  </a>
                              </div>
                              <div class="stats">
                                <a class="card-link" href="#">
                                  <i class="fa fa-comments"></i> 
                                </a>
                              </div>
                              <div class="stats">
                                 <a class="card-link" href="#">
                                  <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> 231 Likes
                                 </a>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            @endforeach
          @endforeach
```

Every item (title,price, body, vendor) occurs 5 times in my view as I have five keys in my array. I am not sure what I am doing wrong with my loop. i have tried a couple of ways but no luck.

Comment: The second loop isn't needed

Comment: that's not valid json...

Comment: To expand on what Charlotte said, the inner `foreach` loop is not just _unnecessary_, it's actually what is causing the problem.

Comment: Why you use second loop and also u did mistake in second loop by using `$key` variable multiple times. You should changed the second `$key` variable.